# S3 Hosting + Api Gateway

Tags: redirect, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to host a static site in S3 with ability to handle some dynamic content using Lambda/Api Gateway. Can't seem to be able to do that.
I want URLs to look like this:

```
example.com/index.html
example.com/images/*
example.com/css/*
example.com/api/* -> API Gateway
```

Also, when redirecting I'd like to keep the example.com as a root domain. I tried RoutingRules in S3, but redirects from the client. I need this to be transparent from the user, like proxying requests.

Comment: How about you expose example.com on just API Gateway alone and based on your path patterns you route the request to backend S3 or Lambda from API Gateway?. Anything starts with `/api` send to Lambda or else send to S3.

Comment: how would I do that? could you share a sample of such api gateway configuration? I already have /api in gateway, how do i tell it to send everything else to S3 bucket?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can configure this by putting a CloudFront distribution in front of both the API Gateway API and the S3 bucket for static content. This would also allow you to take advantage of CloudFront's edge caching.

Comment: could you share some cloudfront configuration details

Comment: Here's a good walkthrough with example CFN templates: https://apimeister.com/2017/05/09/hosting-a-cloudfront-site-with-s3-and-api-gateway.html

Answer (score 15):

While Bob's answer is pretty neat for public websites and is simple but if you are looking for other alternates which can work for internal sites or don't want to use CDN, you can try following options.

Option 1 -

This is most common option people prefer. You just configure 2 different DNS hosts for static vs api.(Assuming you enable proper CORS for *.example.com)

> example.com(S3) --> S3 static content
>
> api.example.com(APIGateway) --> Lambda

Option 2 -

> Example.com(APIGateway) --> /apigLambda -->Lambda
>
> Example.com(APIGateway) --> /* --> S3 Bucket/S3 File.

API Gateway Configuration -

[image]

API Gateway S3 Backend Proxy -

[image]

Example API Urls -

> https://xxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/apigLambda
>
> https://xxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/myfilename.css

Reference -

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html

Note - In above reference Url, the bucket name is being accepted in Url Path but my example hides bucket name so users have no idea of S3 bucket name when they see API Gateway Url.

Option 3 -

As per your comment just use {proxy+} as resource for proxying S3 to support sub-folders calls but as you suggested, making just pass-through proxy doesn't give much options to transform HTTP response body which I believe still ok since you know your website content files.

Comment: I got this working with cloudfront, but would prefer api gateway solution more. Cloudfront doesnt seem to have much flexibility with url paths. To make your proposal work at all levels requires using {item+} signature. That disallows use of AWS services as handler. Another option is to use URL to S3 bucket to proxy to. That works, but instead of nice 404s, I get "The specified key does not exist." S3 error xml.

Comment: I have added one more option if you like and your feedback as one more option. Let me know.

Comment: What drawbacks does Option 2 have?
I don't see it discussed often, but it seems perfect, and certainly better than Option 1.
Is it a recent addition to API Gateway?

Comment: @MihailMalostanidis most likely option #2 will be associated with (much) higher cost as traffic passing through the APIGW is part of the cost